# Get iPhone ID with web app?

Tags: iphone, web

I'm making a web app for iPhone.  I have some settings that the user can set, but I'm not sure how to save the settings for that iPhone.  I don't want the user to have to sign up for an account.  Is there a way to get a unique identifier for the iPhone (serial number, etc).  So basically, what is a unique identifier, and how could I retrieve it with a HTML5 web app?

Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin This needs to be permanent; cookies expire...

Comment: Cookies expire after years after the visitor's last visit. If you're only remembering "some settings" a cookie is quite enough. If you "need" it to be more permanent, you're getting into rather sketchy territory. Tell us why you want this information.

Comment: I suppose cookies would work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to get a UUID (universally unique ID) into an NSString in your iPhone app:

```
CFUUIDRef uuid = CFUUIDCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault);
CFStringRef uuidStr = CFUUIDCreateString(kCFAllocatorDefault,uuid);
NSString* uniqueIdentifier = (__bridge NSString*)uuidStr;
```

From Apple's documentation:

> UUIDs (Universally Unique Identifiers), also known as GUIDs (Globally
>   Unique Identifiers) or IIDs (Interface Identifiers), are 128-bit
>   values guaranteed to be unique. A UUID is made unique over both space
>   and time by combining a value unique to the computer on which it was
>   generated—usually the Ethernet hardware address—and a value
>   representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since October 15,
>   1582 at 00:00:00.

As far as getting the string to your server, how about just sending it in an HTTP POST?

Comment: This is a web app, not a native app.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at http://whatismyudid.com  , if your web offers provisioning profile which is accepted by the user, then website can read even UDID ...

Comment: That actually would work...is there a way to make the profile permanent?  That way when I check the UDID, they won't always have to accept the profile.  ([Also see my question about getting the UDID](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13211972/636848))